# How to deal with 'privileged' teammates always pushing unwanted work to me?

Tags: teamwork, politics

How to deal with 'privileged' teammates always pushing unwanted work to me?

What I find is most of the time my teammates treat me as junior deliberately despite my being in experience terms more "senior" than them. And they consequently always push the least desirable parts in the project to me.

What should I do? It's hypocritical for them to say 'teamwork' all the time, a vocabulary that's exploited by them to put on undesirable work on me, while they take away parts that are way more interesting?

It's been a problem for so long I don't know from where can I start tackling it.

As our manager knows basically nothing about our field, and since our
team's business is not even the core business, he delegate all the
business to one of our peers. He takes all interesting projects and
delegates the rest to teammates. As he doesn't like me/envy of me, he
pushes the worst tasks to me all at once. When I complain to
manager, he stands by their decisions.

Comment: What happened when you talked to your manager about this?

Comment: Beside talking to your manager, why would you have to take that sh**y work? Did you talk to the person about this issue?

Comment: Who is distributing work? What hinders you to take one of the "desirable" parts of the project for yourself?

Comment: Right now this question reads like a rant. It's understandable to be upset, but if you want qualitative answers, you need to provide us with more context. Who assigns the tasks? Why can't you say "no"? Is there a business reason giving the tasks to you being beneficial? What's the opinion of your manager about this?

Comment: how many people are these? how are you senior, in company years or time worked in the relevant job? why are they privileged?

Comment: Question: Why are the parts being assigned to you not 'desirable'? Is it because they are the most technically complex? Or the most critical? Or the most detail orientated? Because these things - though tedious and laborious would certainly be the purview of the most senior person on the team.

Comment: @Student That's quite enough with the ranting profanity please, there's just no need and worse it just makes your question look like a rant. I've edited your question to remove it and that's the second time I've had to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the precieved privilege is real - ie that the company's management will back them over you then realistically there isn't much you can do about that. When it comes to first pick of desired assignments general experience often means little compared to the seniority within the company. The "new guy" gets the rubbish jobs - this is practically a truism in most workplaces.

> What should I do? It's hypocritical for them to say 'teamwork' all the time, a vocabulary that's exploited by them to put on undesirable work on me, while they take away parts that are way more interesting?

They may well be exploiting "teamwork" as a justification for offloading work to you but ultimately they aren't *wrong* either - whether a project or task is "interesting" or not has little to no relation to whether it's *necessary*. While it's smart for organisations to avoid valuable staff getting stuck with the less interesting aspects 100% of the time it can't be all exciting all the time either, because then all that boring-but-necessary work wouldn't get done and projects would fail, hard. Only you can decide what ratio of crap-to-interestig work you can live with - but if its 0:100 then you're going to be in for a bad time in pretty much every job going.

So what should you do in your current situation? I'd suggest a three-pronged approach:

Firstly, accept that there's always going to be a proportion of your work that's undesirable, and that it's probably always going to be more than you'd like it to be. While this might sound depressing, I've found that it's significantly *less* depressing when you remember that regardless of which part of the work you're doing you're still getting paid the same. And that money can be spent on things and experiences that bring you joy, far, far more joy than you'll ever get out of even the most interesting parts of the day job.

Secondly, try to reframe the way you look at these parts of the work - rather than in terms of whether they are "interesting" or "cool" instead look on them as how *important* or "necessary" they are. Some of the work I've done over the years has been the intellectual equivilant of watching paint dry while eating styrofoam but has been absolutely *crucial* from a business perspective, and keeping that in mind can make these things much easier to work on. Plus, if you do some boring-but-vital work for the business all then there's a great deal to be said for being seen as the person who will do what the business needs without complaint even if it's not the most exciting for them personally, and even if all they see is the "vital" part of the equation and that can do wonders for career progression in an organisation.

Thirdly, assuming you have a team lead or manager that provides general work-allocation push with them for work your interested in. Do so in a positive manner; *"I'm really excited to work on the new Widget project!"* rather than complaining about the work you've been doing. No manager likes it when they have someone come to them with (essentially) *"the other kids are being mean to me and won't let me play with their toys"* - that means they've got more work to do to sort that out, yes that's part of the manager's job but sorting out childish squabbles is *their* idea of crap work. On the other hand they *love* employees who eager for work, so in doing this you're simultaneously doing "bring solutions, not problems" *and* staking a proverbial claim on some work you'd like to do. It's win-win.

None of these is going to turn this thing around overnight - but keep at them and things should improve. If they don't then this organisation just isn't right for you, or you for it.

Comment: it's a very neutral analysis with deep insights. Thanks!